# Undergrad: is it reasonable to have a syllabus policy about prolonged student absences from my course?

Tags: teaching

To establish course policy for prolonged student absences which lead to a poor grade half way into the course, do the following modifications to boundary conditions in the syllabus seem reasonable?

- course staff needs to be notified prior to prolonged absences
- course staff cannot doubly-educate/train students who are behind.
- TA meeting/zoom time is for understanding learning objectives
  previously covered, not private lectures/tutorials for catching up
  due to missed lectures.
- students with a score below 50% by week X will be recommended to drop
  the course.
- an incomplete grade will only be given when there are 3 or fewer
  missed assignments (not exams).
- students not in compliance with the above conditions
  will receive a grade based on the total score at semester end

Unfortunately, it seems that boundary conditions in the syllabus need to be continually appended, because if not, students potentially could just take time off from the course and try to salvage everything upon return.  Thus, guard rails in the form of syllabus policy are needed to keep students on task & timelines.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly it is you are asking? Right now this feels more like a statement/description than a question.

Comment: Talk to your institution. There are almost certainly policies in place for cases like this, and you should not bake your own.

Comment: Modified the question about what's being asked.  I will need to research if there is institutional policy. fyi - i never want personal/private medical data/information from students.  My chair states that there's no dept policy on prolonged absences resulting in poor performance, and that salvaging rests with the individual faculty.

Comment: Is attendance compulsory? Then it makes sense to require a note from a doctor. It does not have to state medical details, just acknowledging inability to attend. Is there course mark determined mainly by a final exam or by various smaller marks throughout the year? That will change the procedure strongly. In case of one final exam the only concern is that the student sufficiently prepares for it. Is there only one exact date for the exam or can the student come at various dates? That also changes a lot.

Comment: Prolonged absences aren't necessarily planned absences.

Comment: How does this address absences outside the student's control, eg, in hospital for an emergency, then travel a long distance to another hospital for major heart surgery? It is necessary that everyone be reasonable about absences of all kinds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking these a few at a time (and writing to teaching situations as I understand them to be in the US):

> - course staff needs to be notified prior to prolonged absences
> - course  staff cannot doubly-educate/train students who are behind.
> - TA meeting/zoom time is for understanding learning objectives previously covered, not private lectures/tutorials for catching up due to missed lectures.

These are OK policy-wise, but have no teeth, or a penalty associated with enforcement (your last item notwithstanding).  What do you do for the students who inevitably just don't choose to go along with this?

For the second item, rigorously publishing and adhering to your prerequisites should largely address that, but there will always be cases where students who have passed their prereqs still don't understand the material well enough to thrive in your course.  Welcome to post-secondary teaching.  It may not be your responsibility to teach them that material, but in today's teaching environment, where you can scaffold a course in multiple ways without doing much work, you at least owe it to the students to tell them how to catch up.  Also, it would be wonderful to communicate to the teachers/departments teaching and grading the prereqs when the students don't understand the material in courses that they got passing grades for -- but this may be a matter for your department chair to diplomatically take up.

If by "behind", you just mean that you don't want to simply repeat lecture material for students that don't come to lecture, yes, that's frustrating.  Perhaps you can just add an attendance requirement to the grade scheme, and make it worth enough to have teeth.  Alternatively, you could make your lectures available on video. Yes, I know that has impacts on attendance, and nobody likes lecturing to empty rooms.  This is an issue many of us deal with.  The most success I've had with this was to personally manage access privilege to each lecture, with students who needed access for legitimate reasons emailing me with their excuses.  This is marginally more work for me.  Also, COVID isolation policies forced me to abandon this plan, but those are going away.  It felt manageable when I tried it, though, and I believe I'll go back to it.

For the third item, write it down all you want to, but it remains up to you to train the TAs how to deal with such situations, or it won't make any difference what you actually write down.

> - students with a score below 50% by week X will be recommended to drop the course.

My own opinion is that this is unwise.  Curricula and requirements are very complicated things.  Depending on what your course is, and who needs to take it to graduate, this action may have *many* unpleasant unintended consequences -- for the students, for teachers of "upstream" courses, for your department.  I'd urge you to discuss this with more stakeholders before simply implementing it and letting the chips just fall where they may. I've seen policies like what you'd like to implement in action, and had a ton of very real problems with them.  The way it worked for me, as an academic advisor, was to receive a list of students who were told to drop an important engineering prereq (an some of the letters the students received were really poorly worded and demoralizing), and it was essentially a list of underrepresented minorities that I advised.  "On-ramp" issues for certain students are very real, and need to be identified and fixed.  My own attitude is that if our admissions department is accepting students, then we owe those students every effort to thrive, and excluding them from classes doesn't meet that goal.  In the case I encountered, my reaction was to go to the Deans with my observation, and tell them that if we couldn't find a better way to resolve this, that I would be following up with a civil rights attorney on behalf of my advisees, as these students were being separated from 4-year STEM degrees in ways that might not have been fair or necessary.  In response, we found a better way to identify these students before they found themselves in trouble, and to move them through a slower sequence of prereqs that would give them a real opportunity to hit full speed and still graduate in 4 years with an engineering degree.

While I know the situation you're trying to fix is right up there with the most frustrating things a post-secondary teacher can encounter, I don't believe that your policy can really fix things.

It would be *much better* to formally warn students in this situation that they are very likely to fail the course, and let them make their own decisions about what action they need to take.  It would be *Much, Much* better to identify those students very likely to fail *before* their failure (or forced withdrawal) is carved in stone, and help them to identify what needs to be done to pass.  It would be *much, much, much* better for your school to find a way to deal with on-ramp issues more effectively, and this involves the professors that notice them making a bit of noise.

> - an incomplete grade will only be  given when there are 3 or fewer missed assignments (not exams).

This seems like a reasonable policy on incompletes.  I'd probably try to word it better, and pop it in the syllabus, and make sure students hear and understand your incomplete policy on the first lecture day.  My personal preference would be to provide the date certain by which grades of incompletes must be discussed, leaving an "out" for students with true last minute dire emergencies.

> - students not in compliance with the above conditions will receive a   grade based on the total score at semester end

This need not be said.  In fact, EVERY student should be graded the same way, which is how you say the grade will be generated in your syllabus.  Adding a line like "missing items will receive grades of zero" should be sufficient.

My own preference is to not write a syllabus as if students are expected to find themselves in trouble, or for those students likely to find themselves in trouble.  Write your syllabus to let *every* student know what is acceptable behavior in the course, and hold them to it.  My personal opinion is that until you know the students, they all deserve the same answers to the same questions, and that not doing so is letting confirmational biases work their way in to your processes, and that's sub-ideal.

Comment: I have found that half of my course syllabi consists of "needs not to be said" stuff ("cheating will be reported to the disciplinary committee", etc.). I think emphasising things that should be clear but have historically not been is not the worst thing in the world.

Comment: @xLeitix Unfortunately, you are right. The obvious is not obvious. Especially today, every loophole becomes a slithergap, an escape route, a bottomless pit.

Comment: What stemmed my question was that a student missed the first two months of everything (comp labs, lectures, quizzes, homeworks, etc.) due to "personal reasons," and is now back with one month left, and "can not afford to drop, so I'll just complete the assignments, and meet with you and the TA every week as a substitute for missed lectures."   Would it be fair to other students who participated in everything to not deduct for late submissions, missed attendance?  Can this student get an A+?

Comment: Another thing, I am adjunct, and am not on campus when not lecturing.  This is no different from a calc instructor I once had who was a mathematician at Ford Motor Company.  I enjoyed the fact that she was at Ford and unavailable, because it forced me to realize that I need to get my act in gear, since she won't be around for help.  Come to think of it, one my grad nuc engin profs worked at Ford full-time.   Thus, I don't have office hours -- the TAs do.   I also don't have that kind of time, so students are informed during course intro to meet with TAs.

Comment: @wjktrs - then wouldn't it be a lot more straightforward to just make a policy on the penalties for late work that apply to everybody?  For example, in one class, I don't accept late hw and I drop the lowest hw grade.

Comment: @Scott Seidman - wouldn't you eventually get pushback from the dept, however, that it's impossible not to accept late homeworks/labs?  What if a student misses 2 months like my student did? Graduate later?

Comment: There are draconian policies, and there are less draconian policies.  For example, for hw, I just don't take late work.  It prevents me from getting solution sets out to students.  If a student needs to miss a hw, it can be dropped.  For major assignments, like lab reports, I accept late work, with a half letter grade penalty, and students can choose whether they hand in something less than stellar, or wait to hand in something better with a penalty.

Comment: @wjktrs If a student misses two months, then they will (1) get a zero on a few hw's (2) lose a half letter on major assignments (should they eventually turn them in), and (3) probably do very bad on their exams.  Their grade would be calculated, and if they fail, they fail.  I've been doing things this way for years, and have yet to receive major pushback.   Students with major issues, like health, can always negotiate for an Incomplete, but there need to be real reasons.  Students needing real accommodations have routes to that, as well.

Comment: Needless to say, what I've written here is more than backed up in my syllabus, and I spend about a quarter of the first lecture going through the rules.

Comment: @Scott Seidman - Thanks for the wonderful comments and answer, which I have accepted.  I'm in stats, which is in school of engineering.  Students in the engineering stats course typically have no issues. But students in the biomed stats course (n>130) in psych, chem, neuro, pre-med seem to be in their "comfort zone" too much.  Of late, I say to myself "I wish I only taught engineering students for everything, since I know they would say "you're class is not that challenging for me."  Not true for biomed students, which have much more excess baggage -- hand-holding, babysitting.

Answer (score 6):

In a comment on another answer, you provided some context for the question:

> What stemmed my question was that a student missed the first two months of everything (comp labs, lectures, quizzes, homeworks, etc.) due to "personal reasons," and is now back with one month left, and "can not afford to drop, so I'll just complete the assignments, and meet with you and the TA every week as a substitute for missed lectures."

*"Hard cases make bad law."* This is a specific set of circumstances that have arisen this year, and may not arise in future.  Your proposed syllabus modifications presumably can't be retrospective, so they don't help you deal with this individual. I would therefore suggest focussing on the bigger picture. The following questions seem to be relevant, and should be addressed in your syllabus:

1. **If a student misses a class, how should they catch up?** At least some student absences will be for indisputably-valid reasons (you probably don't want to deal with someone throwing up in your classroom!), so explain what a student should do if they miss a class. Do you have recordings of lectures? What other resources/support are available? How does a student find out what - specifically - was covered in each lecture? Which textbooks cover the material? You could certainly include a note here that "catching up is the student's responsibility, and staff cannot be expected to repeat a class".
2. **What does a student need to do to pass the course?** No doubt this is already covered in your syllabus, but your question suggests that your current policy doesn't actually reflect your expectations. If you believe it is essential that students complete all homeworks, or attend 80% of classes, or get 60% on Assignment 1, or whatever - then build this into your grading policy. Obviously, as part of this you may need to consider your policy on late/unsubmitted assignments.
3. **What are your expectations for office hours/TA support/etc?** How much time is on offer? How will you manage a scenario where multiple students show up with different questions? Once you have set these rules, you need to be firm about enforcing them (and support your TAs to enforce them too).

If all of these questions are answered clearly and fully, it seems like your current situation would be avoided (or at least, could be dealt with by reference to your published rules).

Comment: +1 for “hard cases make bad law.” Or more succinctly: if you don’t have a late penalty and the student uses your regular office hours without depriving other students, then they’re not really doing anything wrong. The only law change that really seems necessary is perhaps a better late policy

Answer (score 5):

These seem reasonable, and I don't see any real problem with doing as you propose. Still, since you asked....

> An incomplete grade will only be given when there are 3 or fewer missed assignments (not exams). Students not in compliance with the above conditions will receive a grade based on the total score at semester end.

The first sentence of this is the only one that really "needs" to be in there, in that it is a policy that students could not otherwise be expected to know. For that matter, you should be sure that this policy is enforceable; incomplete grades may be handled by the college rather than the instructor. (In particular, I am concerned that you may end up denying incomplete grades to students with many missed assignments, when the reason for the missed assignments is precisely the reason that the incomplete is needed in the first place).

> - course staff needs to be notified prior to prolonged absences

I am not sure what the purpose of this is. Prolonged absences may not be planned, and even if they are, the student only needs to contact you if they will be unable to meet deadlines or other course requirements.

> - course staff cannot doubly-educate/train students who are behind.
> - TA meeting/zoom time is for understanding learning objectives previously covered, not private lectures/tutorials for catching up due to missed lectures.

I think this is better left unsaid. Your office hours are arguably for the students to use however they see fit; however, if multiple students show up, you can prioritize the ones who have been attending lecture (or divide time evenly). Outside of office hours, you can bluntly refuse to do anything except answer specific questions that were not covered in lecture.

> students with a score below 50% by week X will be recommended to drop the course.

There is no need to tell them this; you can just reach out at week X. Or, you could put this in your syllabus *instead* of reaching out individually at week X. Doing both seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what the others have written, please double-check your institution's policies. At my last university, your syllabus policy as written would violate the university's rule codex, since students with a legitimate reason for their absences are entitled to certain accommodations (within reason). These included prolonged medical issues, emergencies, specific disabilities, etc. . Not differentiating between a student who just didn't turn up and student who was hospitalised would not have been permissible.

Even if there is no official policy, I would encourage you to check what the guidelines are for such cases. For instance, my university had an "equivalent work" guideline, where students who wanted to still have the same grade would have to show equivalent work (within the constraints of disability) to those who took the course the intended way. If a student missed 2/3rds of the class, it's patently absurd that they would be able to follow the remaining third as usual while also submitting all the late assignments and using all the TA time. Since there is no way for them to achieve the equivalent work, and the grading policy of what needs to be achieved applies equally to everyone by default, they fail (or withdraw, or incomplete depending on your institution).